# Cant add 2 items to a list in brackets

Tags: python, list

I have a simple script. The problem is, when I add the username and password, it gives me an error. I want the code to add the username and password to a list in brackets. This is my code:

```
add_user = 1
password = 2
passwords = []
passwords.append[(add_user, password)]
print(passwords)
```

And the output should be something like this:

```
[(1, 2)]
```

The error:
`TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: EDIT this way: `passwords.append((add_user, password))` append uses parentheses not brackets

Comment: append is a function. so u need to use "()"

Comment: use `passwords.append((add_user, password))` or `passwords[len(passwords):] = [(add_user, password)]`

Comment: It would be useful if you could mention what errors you get

Answer (score 1):

### Option-1

```py
passwords = list()
passwords.append((add_user, password))
```

### Option-2:

```py
passwords = list()
passwords += [(add_user, password)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
passwords.append[(add_user, password)]
```

should be:

```
passwords.append((add_user, password))
```

because `append` is a function.

Answer (score 0):

`append` is a method, which is used for adding an item to a `list`, so it needs to be called with `()`. You can do the below changes to make your code working as required:

```py
add_user = 1
password = 2
passwords = []
passwords.append((add_user, password)) #change is in this line
print(passwords)
```